# Autonomous Pyth Price Feed Updates Without User Wallet Confirmations

Tags: transactions, pda

I'm working on a Solana smart contract that includes functions for creating a Program Derived Address (PDA) to store price data and updating this PDA with data from Pyth price feeds. My goal is to automate the updating process, eliminating the need for manual user wallet confirmations for each transaction.

How can I structure my smart contract so it autonomously covers transaction fees for updating the price account, thus avoiding manual user confirmation prompts? Is such automation feasible within the Solana ecosystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of questions here, and I think it'll help a lot if we separate them.

To start, web and hardware wallets typically require manual confirmation for all transactions that the user signs to avoid potentially putting user funds at risk. This is a basic and crucial security feature of wallets. If they did automatic signatures, then it would be extremely easy to drain a user's funds.

You have two options to solve your problem:

- if the user doesn't need to sign the transaction, but you still want to have a price update, you can have a web2 server that receives user requests, signs the transaction with a hot key on your server, and pays the transaction fee
- if the user does need to sign, you can have them fund a hot key on the website, and then use that to sign transactions without future user confirmation. Just be sure to return any unused funds at the end!